# Taking a sum in python over vectors scaling a variable to graph

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to plot a log-likelihood function in python for the Berthe-Blocke
equation and I keep getting a nonsensical plot. Currently I am taking doing

```
    def Berthe_Blocke(beta, prefac, I):
   gamma=(1/numpy.sqrt(1- beta))
   vsq=beta*9*10**20
   return  prefac*(numpy.log(2*0.511*numpy.power(gamma,4)*vsq*(beta)*2*0.511/ numpy.power((3*10**10)*I,2))-2*beta) #non-vectorized BB Funtion
def Likelihood_sing(I, element,mean, k):
    En=numpy.ones(len(pbe)) #these three make it such that the function is far more general
    sp=numpy.zeros(len(pbe))
    us=numpy.ones(len(pbe))
    beta=numpy.ones(len(pbe))
    spav=numpy.ones(len(pbe))
    esp=numpy.ones(len(pbe))
    prefac=numpy.ones(len(pbe))
    usr=numpy.ones(len(pbe))
    if element=="pb":
        En=pbe
        sp=pbs
        us=pbu
        scale=0.1535*(82/207.2)*4
    if element=="xe":
        En=xee
        sp=xes
        us=xes
        scale=0.1535*(54/131.293)*4
    #var=0
    beta=(1-(numpy.power(3727/ (En+3727), 2))) #from gamma=(E+m)/m
    prefac=2*scale*(1/beta) #prefactor
    #print("uncertianties %f", len(us))
    #print("values %f", len(spav))
    #return -(numpy.sum(sp/numpy.power(us,2))+2*numpy.sum(prefac/(numpy.power(us,2)))*(2*numpy.power(numpy.log(a),2)-numpy.log(a))+8*(numpy.sum((prefac*beta)/numpy.power(us,2)))*numpy.log(a))
    return(numpy.power((sp[k]-Berthe_Blocke(beta[k], prefac[k], I))/us[k],2))-(numpy.power((sp[k]-Berthe_Blocke(beta[k], prefac[k], mean))/us[k],2))
def difLikelihood(I,element,mean):
    dL=0  
    if element=="pb":
        for k in range(len(pbe)):
            dL=dL+Likelihood_sing(I, element, mean, k)
    if element=="xe":
        for k in range(len(xee)):
            dL=dL+Likelihood_sing(I, element, mean, k)
```

and to plot I am giving the command
    t=numpy.arange(1,100, 1) #some dummy range
    matplotlib.plot(t, difLikelihood(t, element, mean)) #mean is set

This gives a function that is completely wrong in shape, but when I try to take the sum as

```
numpy.sum(numpy.power((sp-Berthe_Blocke)/us,2))
```

I get an error complaining about shape mismatch. So my question is, is therre a proper way to do this sum so that I can create a graph in terms of variable "I"? 
(by the way, energy and stopping power are given, as is uncertainty "us" for a large number of trials and I am not allowed to use the built in functions for Log- Likelohood in scipy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the variables were being passed as an integer, and needed to be forced to be used as floats using float(l)